# Update 24/7 app on terminal services without kicking out users

Tags: wix, terminal-services

I need to design installer for system which run 24/7 on terminal server and multiple users use this app simultaneously.

It is possible to proceed with update of such application if users are logged on terminal services and use this app unless I kick them all?

I mean if it is possible to update dll and exe which would be applied for example on next terminal session?

Can I use WIX installer or do I handle it by myself?

Comment: Short of installing side-by-side (new version installs to a new folder, and no shared components exist) I am not aware of any way to achieve this reliably, no. WiX is just a way to compile a Windows Installer file, but it is indeed designed to handle these issues as smoothly as possible with regards to the Restart Manager for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is possible in Linux, however the Windows Installer uses the [Restart Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373524(v=vs.85).aspx) to handle replacing files in use. When the Windows Installer detects files in use, it will prompt you to either attempt to close any applications or schedule the replacement during a reboot. Depending on how you configure the UI during the installation, you can bypass the prompt but you cannot force the replacement without closing the applications.